# Separar ano/mês

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte formato de data:

```
201705
```

Gostaria de colocar uma `/` entre o ano e o mês. Como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se está trabalhando com datas, utilize [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', '201705');
echo $date->format('Y/m');
```

Veja o exemplo no [ideone](http://ideone.com/vJWdah)

Se for apenas uma `string` com esse padrão, pode utilizar [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/substr_replace):

```
echo substr_replace('201705','/', 4, 0);
```

Veja o exemplo no [ideone](http://ideone.com/ByOBr8)

Comment: Ou ainda echo preg_replace('/\d{4}/', '$0/', '201705');

Comment: Você poderia dá-la como alternativa em uma nova resposta, @MarcosXavier

Comment: Pelo fato de ser bem simples, achei por bem complementar aqui ao invés de uma resposta.